# Why is install.package() - building the package from scratch?

Tags: r, installation, package

I installed RStudio and R recently on a new laptop

I installed RTools after I noticed that my "packages" (it's source code) - was being downloaded in a temp. folder under "Users...\AppData\ etc. and I couldn't find the actual package and use them.

The RTools then builds the package from source - I think

This did not happen with my earlier RStudio and R isntalls. The packages were downloaded "cleanly" - I don't remember it going to through the source code build process

```
> install.packages("caret")
also installing the dependencies ‘nloptr’, ‘lme4’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘car’

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘nloptr’ ‘lme4’ ‘caret’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
```

When I say 'y' to this question - it builds it all right.

Versions:
OS: Windows 10
RStudio: 0.99.903
R: 3.3.1

(P.S. I have not been able to install the 'caret' package, the others I could going through this process.)

Comment: You need to install RTools to build a package like this: 

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: The message `These will not be installed` indicates that the package hasn't been installed successfully.

Comment: The linked question you have provided isn't the same issue. Here's a link to question that is related to your problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249980/error-in-r-package-which-is-only-available-in-source-form-and-may-need-compil

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses. Have edited my question.

I don't understand *why* this is happening. Earlier the packages just "downloaded" and sat in the library folder - I don't understand why this time they are being built

Comment: We're running into the same issue at our university, Windows binaries, who are clearly in the repos (you can browse to them: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/) but they fail to install. Totally weird. EDIT: for us it seems to be working now, temporary hiccup at CRAN most likely.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

I installed the package directly from the windows binary zip file:

```
LINK <- "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/caret_6.0-71.zip"
install.packages(LINK, repos =NULL)
```

The links to binaries were found at: https://cran.r-project.org/
See under *Software > R Binaries*