# Can't install RCurl package in R 3.3.2

Tags: r, rcurl

I am using Windows 10, 64 bit PC. I have R 3.3.2 installed on my system. 
I have some work to do with the swirl package in R, so I installed it as well. But, while trying to loading "swirl" package in R `library(swirl)`, system threw an error : package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ and a warning : **Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :** 
  **there is no package called ‘RCurl’**.
I tried to install "RCurl" and it gave an error message : **Packages which are only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘bitops’ ‘RCurl’
  These will not be installed**

Comment: Have you tried switching mirrors or installing Rtools? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249980/error-in-r-package-which-is-only-available-in-source-form-and-may-need-compil

Comment: How did you install `swirl`? It looks like you installed in a way that didn't install dependencies. Try `install.packages(swirl)` and then `library(swirl)`.

Comment: I am getting an error "ERROR: dependencies 'stringr', 'testthat', 'yaml' are not available for package 'swirl'
* removing 'C:/Users/YASH/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/swirl"..... I made the following command  install.packages("swirl", dependencies=TRUE)